# Почему на некоторых девайсах выскакивает ошибка ClassNotFoundException для класса Application?

Tags: java, android

Имеется класс приложения

```
public class MyApp extends Application
{
     @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {...}
    @Override
    public void onTerminate()
    {...}
}
```

В манифесте прописано все

```
 <application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:name=".MyApp"
            >
```

Но вот попадаются девайсы, где вот такой стектрейс идет

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application ru.Company.AppName.MyApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.Company.AppName.MyApp
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4181)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ru.Company.AppName.MyApp
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:967)
at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
```

Comment: какое у тебя апи? 2.2? 2.3.3? попробуй сменить туда сюда =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как и в большинстве случаев, [документация](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm) даёт все ответы, надо лишь её читать.

> android:name
>
> The **fully qualified name** of an Application subclass implemented for the application. When the
> application process is started, this
> class is instantiated before any of
> the application's components.
>
> The
> subclass is optional; most
> applications won't need one. In the
> absence of a subclass, Android uses an
> instance of the base Application
> class.

P.S. Кстати, заметил у вас в наследнике `Application` переопределение метода `onTerminate`. Вы ведь знаете, что, согласно [документации](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onTerminate()),

> It will never be called on a production Android device

?

Comment: Вы намекаете, что что надо писать полное имя с пакетом? Но в стектрейсе то полное имя пишется правильно.

Comment: Да, именно на это я и намекаю. Ранее действительно, в `android:name` допускалось писать имя класса относительно корневого package приложения, но позже от этого тихонько избавились, забив на обратную совместимость.

Comment: да я знаю, что onTerminate() не вызывается :)  
Но его можно вызвать принудительно через IDE   
Хорошо, буду надеяться, что это действительно решит проблему.